# Angular - Upload image to API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API that takes an image and saves it to my drive. It works fine when I use Postman. However when I try to call the API from my Angular service nothing happens. What must I change to be able to upload the image? Thank you.

Here is my component:

```js
onSaveFile(e) {

  this.imagePreviewUploaded = false;
  this.changeImage = false;
  this.fileName = "";

  var image = this.uploadForm.get('img').value;
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('formFile', image);

  this.generalService.uploadGeneralConfigurationLogo(formData);

  this.filePath = defaultImage;
  this.uploadedTries = 0;
  this.toastr.success("Success", "The image has been uploaded!")

}
```

Here is my form to upload the image:

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveFile($event)">

  <div class="row" *ngIf="changeImage">
    <div class="col-sm-12 align-items-center">
      <div class="card">
        <!--Preview-->
        <div *ngIf="filePath && filePath !== ''">
          <img [src]="filePath" [alt]="uploadForm.value.name" class="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{fileName}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Upload preview. Dont forget to save it.:)</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="imagePreviewUploaded">Save</button>
          <a *ngIf="uploadedTries == 0" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="file.click()" class="btn btn-primary">
            Upload
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="uploadedTries > 0" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="file.click()" class="btn btn-primary">
            Upload Diffrent image
          </a>

          <input type="file"
                 #file
                 [multiple]="false"
                 (change)="imagePreview($event)"
                 style="display:none" />
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onCancelFileUpload($event)">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here is my Angular service method to upload image:

```js
uploadGeneralConfigurationLogo(formFile) {
  return this.http.post<GeneralConfiguration>(this.baseUrl + 'generalConfiguration', formFile, { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }  })
}
```

Here is my API:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile formFile)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:/images/logo.png"))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    return Ok(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [subscribe](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) the observable in order to submit the request to API.

> An Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it. You subscribe by calling the subscribe() method of the instance, passing an observer object to receive the notifications.

```js
onSaveFile(e) {

  ...

  this.generalService.uploadGeneralConfigurationLogo(formData).subscribe(
    next: () => {
      // TO-DO Handle success scenario
    },
    error: (err: Error) => {
      // TO-DO Handle error scenario
    }
  );
}
```

As you are returning the boolean result from the `UploadFile` API method, the `uploadGeneralConfigurationLogo` method should return the (observer) value of the `bool` type.

```js
uploadGeneralConfigurationLogo(formFile): Observable<bool> {
  return this.http.post<bool>(this.baseUrl + 'generalConfiguration', formFile);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works now. Just one other small question why does the angular app refresh after upload?

Comment: Hi, hmmm, I don't think the upload will trigger the refresh. Suspect that there is other *thing* that triggers the refresh.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help I will investigate further in this case.

Comment: When I use postman to make the api call the angular app refreshs as well so I think it has to do with the api. The actuall path where I save the data is in ClientApp so I think that because I modified the "ClientApp" it will refreash the page.